# Calculating error for a neural network

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

I have written a back-propagation MLP neural network and I want training to stop when the error is less than or equal to 0.01

I have my dataset which has been split to be 60% training data, 20% validation data and 20% testing data.

My main loop for training and validating is as follows:

```
while (continueTraining) {
    for (int i = 0; i < trainingDataSet.size(); i++) {
        neuralNetwork.train(trainingDataSet.get(i));
    }

    double error = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < validationDataSet.size(); i++) {
        error += neuralNetwork.validate(validationDataSet.get(i));
    }
    error = error / validationDataSet.size();

    if (error <= 0.01) {
        continueTraining = false;
    }
}
```

The weights/biases are only updated during training then once one epoch of training has been completed the validation starts (it doesn't change the weights/biases - just a forward pass) which returns an error.

The `validation` method calculates the error as follows (in Java):

```
double error = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < correctOutput.length; i++) {
    error += Math.pow(correctOutput[i] - outputLayer.getNeuron(i).getValue(), 2);
}
error = error / correctOutput.length;

return Math.sqrt(error);
```

So the `validate` method returns the error for each row of data in the validation dataset which is then summed together and then divided by the number of rows of data in the validation dataset, giving an average error of the entire dataset.

However when running the network, the error never gets to 0.01. The closest I've got it is to 0.018 and as the number of epochs reach a very large number then the error increases.

Am I calculating my error incorrectly or is it just that the error will never get to 0.01?

I thought by stopping training when the error of the validation data is minimised would be the best thing to do.

EDIT: Adding some language independent pseudo-code:

```
while continueTraining is true
do
    for each rowOfData in trainingDataset
        neuralNetwork.train(rowOfData)

    error = 0

    for each rowOfData in validationDataset
        error = error + neuralNetwork.validate(rowOfData)

    error = error / numberOfRowsOfDataInValidationDataset

    if error <= 0.01
        continueTraining = false
```

The response from `neuralNetwork.validate(rowOfData)` is calculated as follows:

```
error = 0
for each output
    error = error + (idealOutput - calculatedOutput)^2

error = error / numberOfOutputs

return sqrt(error)
```

Comment: No, it isn't JavaScript. It's Java.

Comment: Make sure to tag the language you're using in the future.

Comment: I've tagged the language. But ignoring the language, is it possible for the error never to become less than 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is actually possible that the error never goes below a certain level. Neural networks as well as other algorithms of machine learning do not guarantee a result.

You can try to increase your training set to improve network performance if that is possible (if you have more data).

Answer (score 0):

Error on cross-validation set usually behaves like that because after certain point NN starts to overfit (NN model starts to learn "noise" - random regularities in training set, rather then problem you are intersting in). This is the reason you need validation dataset in the first place. Therefore  "stopping training when the error of the validation data is minimised would be the best thing to do" is exactly right thing to do. Other means to prevent ovefitting exists, such as adding regularization, or getting more training samples.

Regarding your code, it seems that it is correct, assuming you want to compute root mean squared error (other error functions can be used, such as MSE or cross-entropy error for classification tasks, thus its worth to specify what kind of error you want to compute, when asking about code correctness).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the comments. I'll just try a different number of inputs to see which model has the smallest error - hopefully 0.01!